# shareOutWarning when deleting a file as service account user in shared drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Some background, we have an application and it uses a service account to manage files in Google Drive. For some reason the service account can't trash or delete files anymore. It was able to do that in the past, but now following error occurs:

```
{
    ...
    "data": {
        "error": {
            "code": 400,
            "message": "",
            "errors": [
                {
                    "message": "",
                    "domain": "global",
                    "reason": "shareOutWarning"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "headers": {
        ...
        "x-rejected-reason": "sharingConfirmationRequired",
    },
    "status": 400,
    "statusText": "Bad Request"
}
```

Code:

```
async function trashItem(drive, fileId) {
    const config = {
        fileId,
        supportsAllDrives: true,
        requestBody: { trashed: true },
    };

    const res = await drive.files.update(config);
    return res.data;
}
```

Error also occurs by using cURL with service account:

```
curl --request PATCH \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILE_ID]?supportsAllDrives=true \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"trashed":true}' \
  --compressed
```

Some changes were lately done regarding data loss prevention (DLP) in Google Drive by the company and files now have classification label 'confidential' by default. If the classification label is changed to a 'public' service account can delete files normally. DLP rule 'warn on external sharing' is turned on. I unfortunately can't affect the DLP rules as they are set by company.

I am assuming that these changes now prevent deletion or trashing as these actions are somehow considered as sharing file to outside of organisation. Service account is considered as an external user based on the documentation.

What is the correct way to handle this kind of situation so that the service account can yet again delete files?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  Have you configured domain wide delegation?

Comment: may want to bug report it https://issuetracker.google.com/bookmark-groups/78025

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Question now contains part of the code that trashes files. Everything else works normally like creating a file, viewing/downloading a file, etc.. Same error also occurs by using cURL.

Comment: I have not configured domain wide delegation for the service account. Do you think that should help in this case?

Comment: Delegation may get you past anything configured with in the workspace domain as you will be impersonating a user on the domain.   Assuming you just shard a directory with the service account you are currently just using a service account as a dummy user who has been granted access to a folder.